# What could cause a VAE(Variational AutoEncoder) to output random noise even after training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I have trained a VAE on CIFAR10 data-set. However, when I try to generate images from the VAE all I get is a bunch of gray noise back. The implementation of this VAE follows the implementation from the book [Generative Deep Learning](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/generative-deep-learning/9781492041931/), but instead of TensorFlow the code uses PyTorch.

The notebook containing the training as well as the generation can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t0EmOo5UjmeRScFtQzpcDEB8u2vYW7Yk?usp=sharing), while the actual implementation of the VAE can be found [here](https://github.com/Kinyugo/generative-deep-learning/blob/main/variational_autoencoder/variational_autoencoder.py).

I have tried:

1. Disabling dropouts.
2. Increasing the dimension of the latent space.

None of the methods show any improvement at all.

I have verified that:

1. The input size matches the output size
2. Back-propagation runs successfully as the loss decreases during training.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for providing the code and a link to a Colab notebook! +1!
Also, your code is well-written and easy to read. Unless I missed something, I think there are two problems with your code:

1. The data normalization
2. The implementation of the VAE loss.

**About 1.**, your `CIFAR10DataModule` class normalizes the RGB channels of the CIFAR10 images using `mean = 0.5` and `std = 0.5`. Since the pixel values are initially in [0,1] range, the normalized images have pixel values in the [-1,1] range. However, your `Decoder` class applies a `nn.Sigmoid()` activation to the reconstructed images. Therefore, your reconstructed images have pixel values in the [0,1] range. I suggest to remove this mean-std normalization so that both the "true" images and the reconstructed images have their pixel values in the [0,1] range.

**About 2.**: since you're dealing with RGB images the MSE loss makes sense. The idea behind the MSE loss is the "Gaussian decoder". This decoder assumes the pixel values of a "true image" is generated by independent Gaussian distributions whose mean is the pixel values of the reconstructed image (i.e. the output of the decoder) and with a given variance. Your implementation of the reconstruction loss (namely `r_loss = F.mse_loss(predictions, targets)`) is equivalent to a fixed variance. Using ideas from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13202), we can do better and obtain an analytic expression for the "optimal value" of this variance parameter. Finally, the reconstruction loss should be summed over all pixels (`reduction = 'sum'`). To understand why, have a look at analytic expression of the reconstruction loss (see, for instance, [this blog post](http://adamlineberry.ai/vae-series/vae-code-experiments) which considers the BCE loss).

Here is what the refactored `LitVAE` class looks like:

```py
class LitVAE(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self,
                 learning_rate: float = 0.0005,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        - `learning_rate: float`:
            learning rate for the optimizer
        - `**kwargs`:
            arguments to pass to the variational autoencoder constructor
        """
        super(LitVAE, self).__init__()
        
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate 

        self.vae = VariationalAutoEncoder(**kwargs)

    def forward(self, x) -> _tensor_size_3_t: 
        return self.vae(x)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        r_loss, kl_loss, sigma_opt = self.shared_step(batch)
        loss = r_loss + kl_loss
        
        self.log("train_loss_step", loss)
        return {"loss": loss, 'log':{"r_loss": r_loss / len(batch[0]), "kl_loss": kl_loss / len(batch[0]), 'sigma_opt': sigma_opt}}

    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs) -> None:
        # add computation graph
        if(self.current_epoch == 0):
            sample_input = torch.randn((1, 3, 32, 32))
            sample_model = LitVAE(**MODEL_PARAMS)
            
            self.logger.experiment.add_graph(sample_model, sample_input)
            
        epoch_loss = self.average_metric(outputs, "loss")
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("train_loss_epoch", epoch_loss, self.current_epoch)

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        r_loss, kl_loss, _ = self.shared_step(batch)
        loss = r_loss + kl_loss

        self.log("valid_loss_step", loss)

        return {"loss": loss}

    def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs) -> None:
        epoch_loss = self.average_metric(outputs, "loss")
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("valid_loss_epoch", epoch_loss, self.current_epoch)

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        r_loss, kl_loss, _ = self.shared_step(batch)
        loss = r_loss + kl_loss
        
        self.log("test_loss_step", loss)
        return {"loss": loss}

    def test_epoch_end(self, outputs) -> None:
        epoch_loss = self.average_metric(outputs, "loss")
        self.logger.experiment.add_scalar("test_loss_epoch", epoch_loss, self.current_epoch)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        
    def shared_step(self, batch) -> torch.TensorType: 
        # images are both samples and targets thus original 
        # labels from the dataset are not required
        true_images, _ = batch

        # perform a forward pass through the VAE 
        # mean and log_variance are used to calculate the KL Divergence loss 
        # decoder_output represents the generated images 
        mean, log_variance, generated_images = self(true_images)

        r_loss, kl_loss, sigma_opt = self.calculate_loss(mean, log_variance, generated_images, true_images)
        return r_loss, kl_loss, sigma_opt

    def calculate_loss(self, mean, log_variance, predictions, targets):
        mse = F.mse_loss(predictions, targets, reduction='mean')
        log_sigma_opt = 0.5 * mse.log()
        r_loss = 0.5 * torch.pow((targets - predictions) / log_sigma_opt.exp(), 2) + log_sigma_opt
        r_loss = r_loss.sum()
        kl_loss = self._compute_kl_loss(mean, log_variance)
        return r_loss, kl_loss, log_sigma_opt.exp()

    def _compute_kl_loss(self, mean, log_variance): 
        return -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + log_variance - mean.pow(2) - log_variance.exp())

    def average_metric(self, metrics, metric_name):
        avg_metric = torch.stack([x[metric_name] for x in metrics]).mean()
        return avg_metric
```

After 10 epochs, that's what the reconstructed images look like:

[image]

Comment: Do you mind explaining the calculation for reconstruction loss further? I have gone through the paper, but the implementation is still not clear to me.

Comment: Also shouldn't the reduction of MSE be sum as per the blog post you linked? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Kinyugo In https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13202, the authors propose to consider sigma (the std parameter of the Gaussian decoder) as a parameter of the VAE loss. You can compute the gradient of this loss wrt. to sigma and obtain that the "best"/optimal sigma is: sigma = MSE(target, reconstructed). This is why I introduced a variable called `mse` in `calculate_loss`. By definition of the MSE, the reduction is `mean`. This optimal sigma is used to compute the Gaussian negative log-likelihood `r_loss`, which is our reconstruction loss (with reduction `sum`, as per my answer).

Comment: I see the loss in this case is bound between -infinity and +infinity. Is there another measure that can be used to determine when to stop training, apart from observing the reconstructions?